# How to Find Source of Temp Tables

Tags: sql-server

In SSMS I see 7 temporary tables, all with names like dbo.#0876219E.  When I end my connection and come back in, they are still there.

I'm not able to query them or get properties on them.  I get errors.

How do I find their source, purpose and what they contain?

Is there a particular system sp that gives info on temp tables -- haven't been able to immediately find one.

Comment: If you restart the SQL service, are they still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temp tables with such names (#, then 8 hex digits) are the temp tables that back table variables - `declare @boris table (...)`

They'll exist as long as the batch that introduced them continues to run. On my lightly loaded dev server, I can see ~30 of them, so I'm guessing there are some which are used/created by SQL Server itself - or possibly by SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables in SQL Server are perfectly normal. They are usually dropped when the database service is restarted (along with TempDB in which they are stored).

If you provide us with more context to where you see these temp tables, that would be helpful.

**EDIT:**

This quote is taken from the following [forum post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost426704.aspx), which summarises the role of `tempdb` nicely:

> tempdb is used for sorting,
>   aggregation, distincts, unions, temp
>   tables and table variables, row
>   versioning. It can also be used for
>   index building.
>
> Oh and cursors

Comment: SSMS-Databases-System Databases-Tempdb-Tmporary Tables
Lists seversal such as dbo.#0876219E, dbo.676A338E, etc.
I can't tell what created these or what the contain; good to know they're normal.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a nice summary of what `tempdb` is used for. There are many thousands of sources, including `SQL Books Online`, but I like this summary.